# Building in VSO takes a long time

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Online to host our source code, and today I have added continuous integration (CI) and set up automated builds.

However, the execution of the builds takes forever. I have created a small test solution (one class with one property) and a test project (with a single test, using NUnit), and the build takes more than 20 minutes to complete.

Is there any way we can speed things up in VSO? Using CI to improve code quality is great - but it is annoying to have to wait 20 minutes before the result has been processed.

Comment: Can you look at the build logs and determine where the time is taken? You can up the verbosity a bit to help.

Comment: Hi @DaveShaw, it's the step "Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control". It takes the 17 minutes of a total of 19.

http://imgur.com/qKLAWXK

Comment: That's not normal, are your source settings in your build definition set correctly?

Comment: That just might be it. I think I might have set the source dir too high in the hierarchy so that way too much source code is retrieved. I will investigate and get back to you (tomorrow).

Comment: Also check you have the drops folder cloaked

Comment: Hi @DaveShaw, I changed the source settings and I /think/ it works now. However, I have run into an issue regarding cloaking. I have taken the liberty to create a new question (almost all results I searched for was several years old). It is located at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027915/the-item-myproject-drops-may-not-be-cloaked-because-it-does-not-have-a-mappe