# The item $/<myproject>/Drops may not be cloaked because it does not have a mapped parent. (type WorkingFolderException)

Tags: continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to set up Continuous Integration on Visual Studio Online, but I am getting a strange error:

```
Exception Message: The item $/<mycollection>/Drops may not be cloaked 
  because it does not have a mapped parent. (type WorkingFolderException)
```

My configuration of the build item is this:

[image: Configuration of Source Settings]

The 'Build defaults' step is configured as:

[image: Configuration of Build defaults]

I must admit, that I am a bit in the blank here - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error as you don't have $/[collection]\drops mapped and thus can't cloak it.

It is also worth point out that you need to have a $[collection][teamProject] in the path as "drops" is not valid at that level unless you have a team project called drops.

In addition the "copy to source control" has been deprecated and none of the new tools will use it. You should use "copy to server" instead that stores the build output as a zip in TFS but not in version control.

Comment: Hi @MrHinsh, thank you for the explanation. I got it to work by specifying "copy to server" and simply removing the cloaking.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error from a build definition created by configuring Continuous Integration from within an Azure Web App (App Service). The cloaked "Drops" folder was set to be created under $/[project]/Drops instead of under $/[project]/[solutionfolder]/Drops.

Once I manually changed the build definition (Edit > Repository > Mappings) to manually include the [solutionfolder] the build started working.